# Error when trying to print a transposed 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

While writing my code I'm getting stuck on I'm trying to return the new transposed array and actually transposing the array itself. I get the error cannot convert int to int[][]. i thought trans would be an array var. the problem code is at the way bottom. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 package workfiles;



 import java.util.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class hw2 {

// Do not modify this method
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try
    {
        int [][] iArray = enter2DPosArray();
        System.out.println("The original array values:");
        print2DIArray(iArray);
        int [][] tArray = transposition(iArray);
        System.out.println("The transposed array values:");
        print2DIArray(tArray);
    }

    catch (InputMismatchException exception)
    {
        System.out.println("The array entry failed. The program will now halt.");
    }

}

    // A function that prints a 2D integer array to standard output
    // It prints each row on one line with newlines between rows
public static void print2DIArray(int[][] output) {

    for (int row = 0; row < output.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < output[row].length; column++) {
            System.out.print(output[row][column] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}




// A function that enters a 2D integer array from the user
// It raises an InputMismatchException if the user enters anything other
// than positive (> 0) values for the number of rows, the number of
// columns, or any array entry
public static int[][] enter2DPosArray() throws InputMismatchException {

    int row=0;
    int col=0;
    int arow=0;
    int acol=0;
    int holder;
    Scanner numScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (row<=0){
        System.out.print("How many rows (>0) should the array have? ");
        row = numScan.nextInt();
    }

    while (col<=0){
        System.out.print("How many columns (>0) should the array have? ");
        col = numScan.nextInt();
    }
    int[][] iArray = new int[row][col];

    while (arow < row) {

        while (acol < col) {
            System.out.println("Enter a positive (> 0) integer value: ");
            holder = numScan.nextInt();
            iArray[arow][acol] = holder;
            acol++;
        }

        if  (acol >= col) {
           acol = 0;
           arow ++;

        }



    }
    //arrayName[i][j]
    numScan.close();
    return iArray;
}


 //!!! problem code here!!!
public static int[][] transposition(int [][] iArray) {

    int m = iArray.length;
    int n = iArray[0].length;

    int trans[][];

    for(int y = 0; y<m; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x<n; x++){
            trans = iArray[y][x] ;
        }

    }
      return trans;
}
```

}

Comment: The compiler-error and the included line-number should give you more than enough info to figure out where that error comes from... Read it closely understand what it means and/or google it.

Answer (score 2):

You missed two things

1.) initialization of `trans`

```
    int trans[][]= new int [n][m];
```

2.)  `trans` is a 2D array

```
   trans[y][x] = iArray[y][x] ;
   //trans = iArray[y][x] ; error
```

**Update :** To form this logic , we need index mapping like this

```
  //    trans                       iArray  
// assign values column-wise         row-wise
    // trans[0][0]      <=        iArray[0][0]
    // trans[1][0]      <=        iArray[0][1]
    // trans[2][0]      <=        iArray[0][2]
```

mean traverse the `iArrays` row-wise  and assign values to `trans` array columns-wise

```
int m = iArray.length;
int n = iArray[0].length;
// iArray[2][3]

int trans[][] = new int[n][m];
//                      3  2
for(int y = 0; y<m; y++){
    for(int x = 0; x<n; x++){
        trans[x][y] = iArray[y][x] ;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you! however it just prints the array over again it does not transpose it.

Comment: @GeorgeJacobFlamburis i am glad that i could help, however that seems like the logical issue ,what exactly you are trying to achieve with this code ?

Comment: im trying to take an array like [1,2,3][4,5,6] and transpose it to [1,4][2,5][3,6].

Comment: @GeorgeJacobFlamburis you mean if user enter 2 rows and 3 columns and you want 3 columns and 2 rows ?

Comment: sorta but the data has to remain in the same order i.e the first row of [1,2,3] becomes the first coulmn but stays [1,2,3] in the new arrray